# Friday's the most cryptic day of the week

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. War paint for alien entering from space station's entrance (9)
6. An island country's capital, Praia, devastated after the loss of republic's leader (4)
10. Search "engine oil" at first… Got it! (5)
11. A price resettled for each spring roll wrapping (4,5)
12. Points towards leader's home (4)
13. Sloppy mind readers taking out notice, making notes to avoid forgetting (9)
16. Real things, fake people? (10)
19. Origins of disturbing zoology: human-orangutan hybrid (4)
21. Led by an international union, we produce a chess champion (4)
22. 1 down director's son, maybe a banker? (10)
26. Serb male ordered to protect 1 down (9)
27. Pass up small change in Laos (4)
31/32. Surprisingly, EU excited over having right to give directive (9,5)
33. President Donald Trump's first American to be supported by KKK's leader (4)
34. 9 down to be crushed to produce fast-moving vessel (9)

**Down**
1. Can two females inside road vehicle, leading to claustrophobic feeling (5,5)
2. A Chinese dynasty's numbers (5)
3. Musk ox's head found in the Spanish capital of Navarre (4)
4. Levantine Biblical character – is God above him? (7)
5. Finally, errors by current monarch lead to dismissal (7)
7. Poker game between two fathers and one journalist (9)
8. State of California facing North Korea's central committee's backing (4)
9. Speaker's sterilized suit (5)
14/29. Those supporting social equality feel bad after top headline in *Times* (3,4)
15. A type of alcohol for mystical being in the forest (4,6)
17. Disorder among crowd in Essex (9)
18. Many turned out to profit (3)
20/30. High-ranking officer, briefly brought inside, murdered without emotion (3-4)
23. Ultimate virtuoso changes organs (7)
24. Greek enemies' leaders supporting Hades? (7)
25. Jewish leader sues corrupt Palestinian preacher (5)
28. *Knockout*: Boxing video essentially following case of intrepid youngster (5)
29. (*See 14 down*)
30. (*See 20 down*)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Another great puzzle! A few miscellaneous comments:

> 26-Across was absolutely *brilliant*. Loved the "wait a second..." moment when I realized exactly what was going on there.
>  17-Down was also impressive: I don't often see hidden word clues with long answers and that smooth of a surface.
>  Not a fan of "points" cluing "any number of compass point letters", as in 12A: I've seen it before and it's definitely an established thing, but I personally think it expands the state space way too much for the solver. It's even less precise in indicating the answer than anagrams, because even long anagrams have a finite number of options!
>  25D's definition was pretty funny -- not how you'd normally clue that answer, but it's not *wrong*.